# Github compare gives different results than GraphQL output

Tags: github, github-api, github-graphql

I am trying to compare two repositories (one is a fork of another), the official way, using `compare` and going back to 2017-02-11:

[https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/compare/master@{2017-02-11}...UnitedBitcoin:master@{2017-02-11}](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/compare/master@%7B2017-02-11%7D...UnitedBitcoin:master@%7B2017-02-11%7D)

Which returns:

```
There isn’t anything to compare.
```

But when I use Github GraphQL to retrieve all commits from both repositories, and then measure the intersection I get 218 commits that share the same `sha`. Below the query I use to retrieve commits from one repo:

```
{
      repository(owner: "bitcoin", name: "bitcoin") {
        defaultBranchRef {
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              history(first: 100, since: "2017-02-11T00:00:00Z") {
                totalCount
                edges {
                  node {
                    committedDate
                    oid
                  }
                }
                pageInfo {
                      startCursor
                      endCursor
                      hasNextPage
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How can this be explained? Why are both results different?

FYI: With "measuring intersection" I mean that I compare the IDs (`sha`) of each commit across both repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The dates on both branches are supposed to define a time *period*, as explained in "[Comparing commits across time](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/#comparisons-across-time)".

In your case though, the exact error message is:

```
There isn’t anything to compare.

We couldn’t figure out how to compare these references, do they point to valid commits?
```

That seems to indicate the fork did not exist in 2017-02-11.
If you compare the [fork against the original repo](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/compare/master...UnitedBitcoin:master), the oldest "forked" commit is from December 2017.
There is no valid commit on the fork (ie specific to the fork) at this date.

Between (since: "2017-02-11T00:00:00Z") and the beginning of the fork (early Dec. 2017), it is possible that you would still find 268 *common* commits (since the fork only started a month later)